# Handlebars multiple ajax requests and template result

Tags: jquery, ajax, api, loops, handlebars.js

This is really a single threading issue and how javascript works natively. However, I have not figured out a way to bypass this.

I have a standard ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
   url: url,
   cache: false,
   success: function (response) {
       // send to handlebars template
       resultsPlaceholder.html(template(response));
   });
});
```

The above works fine.

What I need to do is actually take that result, loop through and run another api request and add it to the original data:

```
$.ajax({
   url: url,
   cache: false,
   success: function (response) {
       $.each(response.results, function(key, value) {
          $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: url + "?id=" + response.results[key].id,
                dataType: 'jsonp',
            }).done(function(return_data) {
                response.results[key].details = return_data.info;
            });
       });
       resultsPlaceholder.html(template(response));
   });
});
```

The obvious problem is that the data getting sent to the handlebars template is happening WAY before all of the ajax requests are done in the loop.

This isn't specific to handlebars. I was just wondering what the convention was to avoid this. I don't want to use a setTimeout, that seems hackish.

Thanks.

Comment: Use a [promise](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)!

Comment: @Ryley wish I had known about this sooner. I've had many a headache dealing with asynchronicity.

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate on Ryley's comment, something like this should work:

```
var promises = [];

$.getJSON(url).done(function(response) {
    $.each(response.results, function(key, val) {
        promises.push($.get(url, {id: val.id}));
    });
});

//When all of the promises are resolved
$.when.apply($, promises).done(function() {
    var responses = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

    //Do what you need to do with responses
    //And then load your handlebars template
    resultsPlaceholder.html(template(responses));
});
```

Explanation:

This just loops through your initial AJAX response and creates an array of promises.  Then you can use `$.when.apply()` since (I assume) you don't know how many items will be in the first response.

Best of luck :)

Comment: Instead of calling it `promises`, I'd recommend `pendingRequests` or even something more descriptive. Makes the code easier to read.

Comment: Fair enough.  If I were writing this for an app myself, I would use something more descriptive.  I used `promises` to emphasize that it was an array of, well, promises.  Thanks for the edits; I kind of just threw it together :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [@Eclecticist's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28380228/18771), there is a somewhat more streamlined version that emphasizes on readability:

```
// just wrap up the cumbersome $.when.apply(...)
$.whenAll = function (promises) {
    return $.when.apply($, $.makeArray(promises));
};

function renderResults($target, template) {
    var pendingRequests,
        url; // = your url

    $.getJSON(url).done(function(response) {
        pendingRequests = $.map(response.results, function (item) {
            return $.get(url, {id: item.id});
        });
    });

    return $.whenAll(pendingRequests).done(function() {
        var html = template($.makeArray(arguments));
        $target.html(html);
    });
}
```

Since `renderResults` returns a promise itself, you can do things like

```
renderResults( $("#target"), niceTemplate ).done(function () {
    alert ("All " + arguments.length + " results finished.");
});
```